# opengrok: HTTP Status 404 - /source/s when trying to open .cpp file via an xref

Tags: tomcat, opengrok

Suppose I'm looking at the .cpp file's source code in the web browser. Now, I want to review the .h file included with #include in this cpp. I'm clicking on the header's file name and instead of browsing its content I'm getting the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /source/s

type Status report

message /source/s

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
```

I suspect that this may be related with opengrok's -w command line switch. The help for this switch says:
"Context of webapp. Default is /source. If you specify a different name, make sure to rename source.war to that name. Also FULL reindex is needed if this is changed."

Cannot understand what exactly does this mean.

I installed opengrok manually: I unpacked source.war to c:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\myapp and my sources are on drive D:\myapp. My generated grok data file is in C:\opengrok.

What path must I pass with -w switch to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/issues/1086
use OPENGROK_WEBAPP_CONTEXT
hth

Comment: Please explain a little bit more what to do with `OPENGROK_WEBAPP_CONTEXT`. Answers should be self-contained, only give links for further references. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to rename `source.war` to `myapp.war`.  In the [tutorial](https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/wiki/How-to-install-OpenGrok#optional-need-to-change-web-application-properties-or-name), `-w` option could be replaced by `OPENGROK_WEBAPP_CONTEXT`.

For example, my data source is under `/data/project/src` and generated opengrok data is under `/data/project`.  What I did in Ubuntu is:

1. rename `source.war` to `project.war`
2. update `WEB-INF/web.xml` inside `project.war` 
   (replace `/var/opengrok/etc/configuration.xml` with `/data/project/etc/configuration.xml`)
3. copy `project.war` to Tomcat's `webapps/project.war`
4. FULL clean reindex is needed for the first time.

   ```
   OPENGROK_WEBAPP_CONTEXT=project OPENGROK_INSTANCE_BASE=/data/project /srv/opengrok-0.12.1.5/bin/OpenGrok index`
   ```